# Count occurrences in a csv with Bash

Tags: bash

I have to create a script that given a country and a sport you get the number of medalists and medals won after reading a csv file.

The csv is called "athletes.csv" and have this header

id|name|nationality|sex|date_of_birth|height|weight|sport|gold|silver|bronze|info

when you call the script you have to add the nationality and sport as parameters.

The script i have created is this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
participants=0
medals=0
while IFS=, read -ra array
do
    if [[ "${array[2]}" == $1 && "${array[7]}" == $2 ]]
    then
        participants=$participants++
        medals=$(($medals+${array[8]}+${array[9]}+${array[10]))
    fi
done < athletes.csv
echo $participants
echo $medals
```

where array[3] is the nationality, array[8] is the sport and array[9] to [11] are the number of medals won.

When i run the script with the correct paramters I get 0 participants and 0 medals.
Could you help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?
Note I cannot use awk nor grep

Thanks in advance

Comment: bash arrays are 0-indexed

Comment: You're absolutely right! Thanks a lot for the tip. I have adapted the code but it's still showing 0,0

Comment: Just so you know, by keeping `$1` and `$2` unquoted you will be able to use globs in it

Comment: There's a missing `}` in `${array[10]`. FYI you can get rid of expansions in arithmetic expressions: `medals=$(( medals + array[8] + array[9] + array[10] ))`

Comment: In the header the delimiter seems to be `|`, so is there a reason why you are using `IFS=,` instead of `IFS='|'`?

Comment: `participants=$participants++` appends the string `++` to `$participants`. For incrementing the variable you can use `(( participants++ ))`

Comment: please update the question with a sample of the input file, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output (making sure both sets of ouput correspond to the sample input)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>**I'm assuming that the field delimiter of your CSV file is a comma but you can set it to whatever character you need.**</sup>

Here's a fixed version of your code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

participants=0
medals=0
{
    # skip the header
    read

    # process the records
    while IFS=',' read -ra array
    do
        if [[ "${array[2]}" == $1 && "${array[7]}" == $2 ]]
        then
            (( participants++ ))
            medals=$(( medals + array[8] + array[9] + array[10] ))
        fi
    done
} < athletes.csv

echo "$participants" "$medals"
```

**remark:** As `$1` and `$2` are left unquoted they are subject to glob matching (right side of `[[ ... == ... ]]`). For example you'll be able to show the total number of medals won by the US with:

```sh
./script.sh 'US' '*'
```

---

But I have to say, doing text processing with pure shell isn't considered a good practice; there exists dedicated tools for that.
 Here's an example with `awk`:

```sh
awk -v FS=',' -v country="$1" -v sport="$2" '
    BEGIN {
        participants = medals = 0
    }
    NR == 1 { next }
    $3 == country && $8 == sport {
        participants++
        medals += $9 + $10 + $11
    }
    END { print participants, medals }
' athletes.csv
```

---

There's also a potential problem remaining: the CSV format might need a real CSV parser for reading it accurately. There exists a few `awk` libraries for that but IMHO it's simpler to use a CSV‑aware tool that provides the functionalities that you need.
Here's an example with [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```sh
mlr --icsv --ifs=',' filter -s country="$1" -s sport="$2" '
    begin {
        @participants = 0;
        @medals = 0;
    }
    $nationality == @country && $sport == @sport {
        @participants += 1;
        @medals += $gold + $silver + $bronze;
    }
    false;
    end { print @participants, @medals; }
' athletes.csv
```

Comment: Based upon the heading `id|name|nationality|sex|...` you may want to mention the alternative separator of `'|'` since, at times, CSV is used to refer to a general delimited file without regard to a specific delimiter. Nice job on multiple solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

nation_arg=$1
sport_arg=$2

declare -i participants=0
declare -i medals=0
declare -i line_num=0

while IFS=, read -r _ _ nation _ _ _ _ sport ngold nsilver nbronze _; do
    (( ++line_num == 1 )) && continue   # Skip the header
    [[ $nation == "$nation_arg" && $sport == "$sport_arg" ]] || continue
    participants+=1
    medals+=ngold+nsilver+nbronze
done <athletes.csv
declare -p participants
declare -p medals
```

- The code uses named variables instead of numbered positional parameters and array indexes to try to improve readability and maintainability.
- Using `declare -i` means that strings assigned to the declared variables are treated as arithmetic expressions.  That reduces clutter by avoiding the need for `$(( ... ))`.
- The code assumes that the field separator in the CSV file is `,`, not `|` as in the header.  If the separator is really `|`, replace `IFS=,` with `IFS='|'`.